# In C, I understand why not to return the address of a local variable in a pointer returning function, how can I fix it though?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
int* foo(){
int x = 15;
return &x; }
```

Which I understand why not to do since the local variable address gets erased from the stack after the function finishes and it becomes a dangling pointer. The question is, how do I not make it a dangling variable without making x a static variable

Comment: Allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: What is the use case? For an `int`, you should just return the int instead.

Comment: No, the question is: _why_ does this function need to return a pointer? You don't return pointers from functions unless you have specific reasons to do so. Normally they will return something by value. Returning a pointer is a specialized use-case.

Comment: why do you want to avoid `static`? is it caused by issues with threading?

Comment: @tstanisl threading or not, returning the address of an integer is the wrong approach anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blessed ways are:

- return a value and not an address

  ```
    int foo(){
        int x = 15;
        return x;
    }
  ```
- have the caller to provide an address

  ```
    int *foo(int *x) {
        *x = 15;
        return x;
    }
  ```

  or

  ```
    void foo(int *x) {
        *x = 15;
    }
  ```
- Return dynamic (allocated) memory:

  ```
    int *foo() {
        int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
        // should test valid allocation but omitted for brievety
        *x = 15;
        return x;
    }
  ```

  Beware, the caller will take *ownership* or the allocated memory and is responsable to free it later.

Comment: if you use a newer C standards you can use a variable with `static _Threadlocal` storage. It is quite similar to static but it's thread-safe

Comment: @tstanisl But is is still static inside a thread, while OP explicitely said that they did not want to make the variable static.

Comment: yes, but maybe OP looks for alternative to `static` due to issues with threading

Comment: With no reference to threading in the original question, I will not add this to my answer. But you could post your own if you want to.

Answer (score 5):

Either allocate memory from the heap inside the function

```
int *f() {
  int *foo = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if(!foo) {
    // Do appropriate error handling here
  }
  return foo;
}
```

Don't forget to `free` it at some point though.

Or you pass in a pointer to a variable living outside the function:

```
void f(int *foo) {
  *foo = 42;
}

void g() {
  int goo;
  f(&goo);
}
```